# PHP code with google reCaptcha not sending email

Tags: php, html

My php webform was working until the point I added an if(isset) and also a reCaptcha.

Help?

Tried to debug the code - could not find an issue

html

```
<form class = "form-inline d-flex justify-content-center" action="contact.php" method = "post">
     <div class="mc-field-group-1">
       <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="mce-LNAME"/>
     </div>
     <div class="mc-field-group-2">
       <input name = "email" type="text" placeholder="Email address*" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required/>
     </div>
     <div class="mc-field-group-3">
       <input name = "subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL"/>
     </div>
     <div class="mc-field-group-4">
       <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="39" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key(have the real key here in my code)"></div>
         <div class="clear">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" value="Send">
       </div>
      </form>
```

php

```
<?php

     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];
      $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
      $recipient = "realemail@gmail.com";
      $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

      $secretKey = "my_key(have the real key here in my code)";
      $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
      $UserIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$UserIP";

      $response = file_get_contents($url);
      $response = json_decode($response);

      if ($response ->success)
      {
      mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
      echo "Thank You!";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Invalid Captcha, Please Try Again";
      }

}
  ?>
```

When I click 'Send' in the form takes me to the contact.php page but email not sent to my gmail inbox. Has nothing to do with gmail as I said was working before I tweaked the code to add the reCaptcha.

Comment: Did your code enter here: `if ($response ->success) {`

Comment: What happens if you rename the captcha input from submit to something else, as it might interfere with other code

Comment: You may have a blind spot in your reasoning. You assume GMail has nothing to do with it. You have to make sure that is the case. An assumption is not enough. Try another mailbox, for instance of the provider of your home connection.

Comment: you were right @Mark_Ed it's the gmail. Used mailinator testing inbox and worked :( bloody gmail